# Remove empty array into a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've this array in PHP made dynamically:

```
Array
(
    [Africa] => Array
        (
            ...
        )
    [Asia] => Array
        (
            [] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 
                    [country] => 
                )
        )
)
```

How can I remove empty array to have the following result please ?

```
Array
(
    [Africa] => Array
        (
            ...
        )
    [Asia] => Array
        (

        )
)
```

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the top level of your array, using `array_filter` to remove empty values from each item in the array:

```
foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    $arr = array_filter($arr, function ($v) { return $v['id'] != '' || $v['country'] != '';});
}
print_r($array);
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/qvSt0)